# About texhash as a user and not as a root

Tags: document-classes

I use Texmaker 4.4.1.

I use Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

I've installed birkjour.cls as a root, and everething works fine as a root.

When I try to run  a file as a user using \documentclass{birkjour}, I've got:

! LaTeX Error: File `birkjour.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or  to proceed,

or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.

How can I fix it?

Best

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) Where and how did you install `birkjour.cls` as root? (3) Did you remember to run `texhash` as root after you installed it?

Comment: Thanks for answering!.

I put it:
opt/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/mypkg/birkjour/birkjour.cls.

I run texhash as a root after the installation, and as a root I can compile documents, but not as a user.

What else should I do?

Comment: That's a slightly strange place. If in a terminal you run `kpsewhich article.cls` what result do you get?

Comment: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls

Comment: Unless you set up something special that installation (which is old) will never read anything from `/opt/local/share/texmf....` I've never seen any setup that would organize the packages like this. Unless you need `birkjour.cls` for many articles, just place it in the same folder as your article

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I downloaded MacTeX-2015 from https://tug.org/mactex/ . I run texhash, and now I can compile as a user and as a root. But I wonder, in your opinion, where should it be birkjour.cls?

Comment: MacTeX (AFAIK) still does not use anything in `/opt`, you might want to place it in the `texmf-local` folder, you can find it via `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`, place the `.cls` in `<path to texmf-local>/tex/latex/birkjour/` and then run `texhash`. On a Mac this is easiest via the terminal (remember to use `sudo`)

Comment: It worked before with MacTeX-2015, but I follow your instructions, and it also works. Thank you for your attention

Comment: @daleif Can you provide some kind of answer please?

Answer (score 1):

First of if you just need a journal class as a one of, place it in the same folder as your `.tex` file, no installation needed.

If you want to use it for many projects, then the `texmf-local` folder is the proper place to add it **not** the general LaTeX installation.

You can ask your installation where the "local" folder is via the command

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
```

(mine is `/opt/texlive/texmf-local` as I've installed TL under `/opt/texlive/year/...`)

Thus you would need to go to `/opt/texlige/texmf-local/tex/latex/birkjour/` and place the relevant files there.

Then remember to run `texhash` (as root if you are on a Mac) to the the file database updated.

Remember to test that it works (from a different folder than the one holding `birkjour.cls`)

```
kpsewhich birkjour.cls
```

If nothing is returned LaTeX cannot find the file. If something is returned, you are ready to go.